Is it possible to create Apple Developer Account from India with US billing address and US card?
I would like to know whether I will be able to create a developer account from India with my iPhone bought from US with US billing address and US Debit card and US ID card? I was getting network error.

The last time I checked Apple asks you where your residence is and you’d be fraudulently signing up unless you were an agent of a corporation with address in the US or your lawyers agreed you were a resident of the US while applying from India (and the ID card helps prove residence)
Many things are possible with VPN however, thinking down the line you may risk being banned for life or shorter time if you are don’t fill out Apple’s legal agreements correctly.
As a developer you may be asked to upload official documentation establishing your corporation or personal status and you will be filling out tax forms as well should you apply for paid app distribution. How will you plan on filing taxes on the revenue?
Unless there’s some back story you didn’t post, this seems ill advised unless you work with Apple to have them assist in this US based registration while you happen to be out of the country. They will surely help you pay and register if everything meets their rules.
The place you can get help is the Apple online store since until you are a paid developer, they are going to process your initial payment.

https://contactretail.apple.com/Solutions

I would sign into the US store with the Apple ID you hope to use and make sure your shipping address, US payment all match and even add something to the cart, then reach out for pre-sales support.

Yes, it is entirely possible.
Make sure that your iPhone region and App Store region is set to United States.
